# Communication between wear OS and Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, wear-os

What are the steps involved in linking a Wear OS application and an Android Flutter application to enable communication between them, and what tools or frameworks can be used to simplify this process?

I am looking to establish an open pathway for communication between a Wear OS application and an Android Flutter application.